# How do I convert a hypothetical JavaScript library into a publishable NPM package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am creating a hypothetical JavaScript library for some kind of rapid API development:

```js
import { get, post, put, status } from 'my-awesome-api-library'
import { User } from './entities/User.entity'

get('/users/:userId', async ({ path }) => {
  const user = await User.find(path.userId)
  if (! user) {
    return status(404).with({ errorMessage: 'User not found!' })
  }
})

post('/users', async ({ body }) => {
  return await User.create({
    email: body.userEmail,
    name: body.userName,
    password: bcrypt(body.userPassword)
  })
})
```

1. What is the best way to create the hypothetical functions such that they are publishable to an NPM package?
2. Do I need to take into consideration different export methods? (e.g. `modules.export` vs `export default`)
3. Are there any good examples of how to strongly type this hypothetical library with TypeScript? (I have seen examples for `*.d.ts` files but I am unsure of how to structure that within an exportable library)

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: `.d.ts` file can generated from both js and ts.but there is lake of type information in javascript.You also need to have a npm account. use `npm login` to login your account. and `npm publish`.

Comment: @Nur thanks for your advice on the NPM publishing side of things. I think I am looking for more as a whole best practices for this sort of thing and how a developer would go about making their library public. For example I have this useful library that I have been using for my own benefit for a while - what is the process/best practices for making this open source to people without making them include and compile the files themselves? (i.e. letting them import my package)

Comment: you need to compile your typescript library.publish it (compiled version) to npm.[package.json should look something like this](https://github.com/nurmohammed840/outlooks/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: Hypothetically, there's lots of guides on how to do this. Alternatively, you could just look at an existing packages repo. Here's [one I prepared earlier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-powershell).